# ClassNotFoundException from maven dependency but class exists and is in classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, classnotfoundexception

After many days searching from a similar problem and its solution on the internet, I now please request your help.

First of all I'm working with :

**Java 8 (openjdk), Maven 3, Tomcat 8.5 and I use Eclipse-2019-09 as my IDE.**

For this project I'm build a war with maven, adding the ressource to a tomcat server and start it.

Now the problem is whenever I try to launch my tomcat server I get this error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.stax2.ri.Stax2EventFactoryImpl
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

**Edit : to be more precise, this error append when a bean is getting created. The bean name is "sessionFactory" and its class is : org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean**

I firstly thought that Eclipse wasn't resolving the stax2 dependency but when I looked in the classpath the dependency was there. (As you can see on the picture bellow)

[dependency in Eclipse pom.xml view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1lvw.png)

So I thought maybe the jar may not contain the required class but still, when opening the jar in the navigator the class is there.

[opened jar in the navigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3veo.png)

The last thing I had to check was to see if the jar file was contained in the war file that is built after compiling the project and still, the class is there.

[class exists in War file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tij5q.png)

So, **What have I tried :**

- Maven>Update Projects, Clean/Rebuild project, Maven clean/install and compile the project, clean the tomcat work directory, republish etc.
- Unistall/Reinstall Eclipse, deleting every hidden folders.
- Delete the project, clone it to a fresh new workspace.
- Changed the version of stax2 in my pom.xml
- Checked if the jar missing is in the deployed war
- Deleted my .m2/repository
- Loaded the stax2-api as the first dependency in my pom.xml

The strange thing is that whenever I clone the project on a co worker computer, he can compile/start the server without any exceptions.

I'm a bit lost I must admit, spent a lot a time searching on forums an answer but everything I tried resultd as a failure.

Well, thank you for reading me, if someone has any idea, let me know.

Comment: Did you check the lib directory in the deployed and exploded webapp war within your eclipse tomcat to see if the jar file is present you expect?  It should be {Your_Workspace}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/{Your_App}

Comment: Since it's working on your colleague's machine, the project appears to have the correct dependencies. Try deleting your ".m2/repository" and then run your maven goal again.

Comment: @churd  I did and the jar is actually just there, really strange.

Comment: @northwolf it could be the jar is corrupt.  Make sure the class that isn't found is actually in the jar.  Also the previous suggestion to delete your .m2/repository would fix corrupt jars if that is the case

Comment: @churd the class is in the jar, right now I'm trying Prasanna's suggestion, be right back

Comment: @Prasanna Hey, tried your suggestion but still the same issue..

Comment: well load this lib 1st then load the rest of the lib, i had same issues for some other lib.

Comment: @stacktome Hey there, I'll try that, be right back

Comment: @Stacktome loaded the lib as my first dependency in maven and did not work